# Can a follow-follow conflict exist in a grammar?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, ll-grammar

I know that First/First and First/Follow conflicts exist in a grammar which makes the grammar "not LL(1)". I was just wondering if Follow/Follow conflict exist in a grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it requires an unusual configuration to make it happen. Consider the following grammar, which has been augmented with a new start symbol:

> S' → S$
>
> S → tT
>
> T → A | B
>
> A → ε
>
> B → ε

Now, let's imagine trying to fill in our LL(1) parse table, which is shown here:

```
          $          t
     +----------+----------+
 S'  |          | S' -> S$ |
     +----------+----------+
 S   |          | S -> tT  |
     +----------+----------+
 T   | T -> A   |          |
     | T -> B   |          |
     +----------+----------+
 A   | A -> e   |          |
     +----------+----------+
 B   | B -> e   |          |
     +----------+----------+
```

Notice that there are two items in the entry for (T, $). And that makes sense: if we have the active nonterminal T and see a $, we know that we need to select a production that's going to expand out to the empty string. And we have two different ways of doing this: we could use T → A or T → B, with the ultimate goal of expanding each of those nonterminals out to the empty string. This is a problem - we can't predict which route to take.

Now, what sort of conflict is this? It can't be a FIRST/FIRST conflict, because FIRST(A) = {ε} and FIRST(B) = {ε}, so neither A nor B has any terminals in its first set. It can't be a FIRST/FOLLOW conflict for the same reason.

That means that it's the rare FOLLOW/FOLLOW conflict - we know that we'd choose the production based on what's in the FOLLOW sets of A and B, and yet they're exactly identical to one another and so the parser can't choose what to do next unambiguously.

Comment: Great example. But is it a formal grammar? The terminal set T is empty.

Comment: It should be possible to edit this grammar to give it at least one terminal. Let me go do that now.

Comment: The production rule S'->S$ must be placed under "t" column instead of "$" column.

Comment: @SaiCharan Good catch - sorry, that's a holdover from an earlier version of the grammar. Let me get that fixed...

Answer (score 1):

This is prehaps a simpler example

```
S → A a 
A → B | C
B → ε
C → ε
```

Here, since `a` is both in the `FOLLOW` of `B` and `C`, on `(A, a)` there will be a conflict between `A → B` and `A → C`. Note that there are no other conflicts.